# VueJS Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.img.loadImg is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having this problem and idk how fix this!
Error in render:

```
TypeError: _vm.img.loadImg is not a function.
```

I wanna show the pic with a method `loadImg(id)`, how I use this? I'm a novice in vue.

Code:

---

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import AsyncComputed from 'vue-async-computed'
Vue.use(AsyncComputed)

export default {
  name: "Sell",
  components: {
    Header
  },
  data() {
    return {
      divBar: DivBar,
      iconNext: IconNext,
      iconVaca: IconVaca,
      iconPeso: IconPeso,
      iconPreco: IconPreco,
      iconLocal: IconLocal,
      timelineItems: [],
      errorObj: {
        isSet: false
      },
      img: '',
    }
  },
  computed: {
    loadImg(id) {

      this.$http.get(this.$api + "/midiasvenda/" + id)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.success != null) {
            return response.success;
          } else {
            return Vaca
          }
        }).catch(error => {
          return error;
        })
      return Vaca;

    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div v-else class="container-sell">
    <div v-for="item in timelineItems" :key="item.id" class="container-cow">
        <div class="left-content">
            <div class="flock-image">
                <img :src="img.loadImg(item.id)" alt="" class="cow">
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for help guys!

Comment: Replace `img.loadImg(item.id)` with `loadImg(item.id)`, because `loadImg` function doesn't exist on `img`.

Comment: the error continues: TypeError: _vm.loadImg is not a function

Comment: You should move your `loadImg` to `methods`.

Comment: okay, its works, but the image is not loaded, can you help me ?

Comment: Does `this.$api+'/midiasvenda/'+id` load the image itself?

Comment: I fixed this, dude, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the line:

```
<img :src="img.loadImg(item.id)" alt="" class="cow">
```

Firstly you will need to change this to:

```
<img :src="loadImg(item.id)" alt="" class="cow">
```

Secondly, you can't have a computed property with a parameter. You'll need to create a method instead with the same functionality. Example:

```
methods: {
  loadImg(id) {
    this.$http.get(this.$api + "/midiasvenda/" + id)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.success != null) {
          return response.success;
        } else {
          return Vaca
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        return error;
      })
    return Vaca;
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is a [basic example](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/441967/)

Answer (score 0):

The following line:

```
<img :src="img.loadImg(item.id)" alt="" class="cow">
```

should actually be:

```
<img :src="loadImg(item.id)" alt="" class="cow">
```

because the method `loadImg(item.id)`does not belong to the `img` data property.